# Decrypt Values In a String

Tags: c#, encryption

I have the following connectionString `string`:

```
"DataSource=R7gIrRzkARUJsQBUYXKCPpH8MdqtQ5Sd+lt4kyBEZBY=; userid=weRGgY7PERBTg2WPPzVerIlMP93kmQbTSuKsJKyDHFU=; password=qcMxEGU75lJ1VD5OaaujnLzleR/7ZQDco3kddfwTOvI=;"
```

After I pass the string to a decrypt function, I will use it in the following:

```
iDB2Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

My question is, what's the best way to decrypt the values in the connectionString string?

One possibility was to convert the string to a `DataSet` and call the following code:

```
String connection = dsConnection.Tables[0].Rows[0]["connectionstring"].ToString();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder DBConfig = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection);
string ConnectionString =
                "Data Source=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.DataSource)
                + ";Initial Catalog=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.InitialCatalog)
                + ";User ID=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.UserID)
                + ";Password=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.Password);
```

but I haven't figured out how to do that successfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt and decrypt a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

Comment: What doesn't work?  What errors or invalid results do you get?  Is the problem on the decryption or the parsing of the encrypted connection string?

Comment: @DStanley If I were to move forward with the `DastSet` method, I am unsure how to parse the connectionString correctly into the `DataSet` format I am looking for.

Comment: What does adding the string to a `DataSet` buy you? Seems like you just pull the string back out to pass it to `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: @DStanley I agree. Thus we can skip the `DataSet` step. My question would then be, how do I go from `string` to `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` correctly? When I call the following line:  SqlConnectionStringBuilder DBConfig = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("DataSource=R7gIrRzkARUJsQBUYXKCPpH8MdqtQ5Sd+lt4kyBEZBY=; userid=weRGgY7PERBTg2WPPzVerIlMP93kmQbTSuKsJKyDHFU=; password=qcMxEGU75lJ1VD5OaaujnLzleR/7ZQDco3kddfwTOvI=;");  I get an error of "Keyword not supported: 'datasource'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your *source* is an *OleDb* connection sting, not a *SQL Server* connection string.  I would recommend using an `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` instead:

```
var connectionString = "DataSource=R7gIrRzkARUJsQBUYXKCPpH8MdqtQ5Sd+lt4kyBEZBY=; userid=weRGgY7PERBTg2WPPzVerIlMP93kmQbTSuKsJKyDHFU=; password=qcMxEGU75lJ1VD5OaaujnLzleR/7ZQDco3kddfwTOvI=;";

var DBConfig = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string ConnectionString =
            "DataSource=" + Decrypt(DBConfig["datasource"].ToString())
            //+ ";Initial Catalog=" + Decrypt(DBConfig.InitialCatalog)
            + ";UserID=" + Decrypt(DBConfig["userid"].ToString())
            + ";Password=" + Decrypt(DBConfig["password"].ToString());
```

You *could* try to map the decrypted values from the source string to a Sql Server connection string, but I don't see a `database` key that would normally be present if you were connecting to a SQL server through `OleDb`.

Comment: Thank you I believe this is going to work. Now I need to complete the Decrypt function. Regarding your answer, from a learning perspective, how did you know that; how did you learn that?

Comment: I looked up the documentation for [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), realized that your source string was for Ole Db, not SQL, and searched for [`OleDbConnectionBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) as an alternative.